# iOSアプリでオフィス系ファイル(docs,pptx,xlsxなど)からPDFへ変換しての出力

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

iOSの自作アプリ内でオフィス系のファイル(docs,pptx,xlsxなど)を読み込み
PDFに変換してから、アプリ内領域に変換したPDFを吐き出すという処理を行いたいと思っています。

上記のような、コンバート処理を行うメソッドもしくは、それを簡易的に行えるライブラリなどはないでしょうか？

※現在は、外部サーバからオフィス系のファイルをDLして、NSDataに保管して元の拡張子で吐き出すということはできているのですが、これをPDF形式として吐き出したいのです。

docファイルをNSDataに格納　→　pdfでファイル出力　といった形です。

どうぞ、宜しくお願いします。